# Inequality of a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I've been asked to prove that $\sqrt{2} |z| \geq |Re(z)| + |Im(z)|$. I have thought a lot about this problem, however I have not been able to prove it yet.

I proved that $2|z| \geq |Re(z)| + |Im(z)|$ in the way that follows:

Let $z = x +iy$, then $|z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \geq |x| = |Re(z)|$. In the same way we found that $|z| \geq |y| = |Im(z)|$.

Therefore, $2|z| \geq |Re(z)| + |Im(z)|$.

Does someone have any tip to help me with this inequality?

Comment: this is $2(x^2+y^2) \ge (x+y)^2$ which after simplification is the usual mean inequality and follows from $(x-y)^2 \ge 0, x=|\Re z|, y=|\Im z|$

Comment: I can see it now. Thank you, Conrad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

$$\sqrt{2} |z| \geq |Re(z)| + |Im(z)| \iff \sqrt{2(x^2+y^2}  \geq |x| + |y|$$

and squaring both sides

$$2x^2+2y^2\ge x^2+y^2+2|xy| \iff \frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\ge |xy|$$

which is true by AM-GM or equivalently

$$2x^2+2y^2\ge x^2+y^2+2|xy| \iff (|x|-|y|)^2\ge 0$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't try to use the inequality itself to prove it. Your answer was very helpful. Thank you again.

Comment: @JeanWeigel Of course there are many ways to prove it. You are welcome! Bye